# How to configure the state store in dapr with statestoretype in-memory

Tags: c#, docker, .net-core, asp.net-web-api, dapr

I am getting the below exception while trying to save key value in the Dapr statestore .I am new to the Dapr concepts .

Dapr.DaprException: State operation failed: the Dapr endpoint indicated a failure. See InnerException for details.
---> Grpc.Core.RpcException: Status(StatusCode="FailedPrecondition", Detail="state store is not configured")

I have used the below yaml file and c# code .

filename: config.yaml

```
apiVersion: dapr.io/v1alpha1
kind: Configuration
metadata:
  name: daprd-config
spec:
  stateStore:
    - name: statestore
      stateStoreType: inMemory
```

Program.cs file

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Dapr.Extensions.Configuration;
namespace DaprPoc
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //// Set the DAPR_CONFIG environment variable to the path of your config file
            //System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("DAPR_CONFIG", "/path/to/config.yaml");
            var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
            // Add services to the container.
            builder.Services.AddCors(x=>x.AddPolicy("EnableCors",
                y=>y.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod()));
            builder.Services.AddControllers().AddDapr();
            //builder.Host.ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
            // {
            //     config.AddDaprConfig(builder =>
            //     {
            //         builder.AddYamlFile("mydapr.yaml");
            //     });
            // });
            // Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
            builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
            builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
            var app = builder.Build();
            // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
            if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseSwagger();
                app.UseSwaggerUI();
            }
            app.UseCloudEvents();
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseCors();
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapSubscribeHandler(); // add this line if you want to enable pub/sub
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
            app.Run();
        }
    }
}
```

Controller

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Dapr.Client;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors;
namespace DaprPoc.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    [EnableCors("EnableCors")]
    public class StateManagementController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly DaprClient _daprClient;
        public StateManagementController(DaprClient daprClient)
        {
            _daprClient = daprClient;
        }
        [HttpGet("{key}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<string>> Get(string key)
        {
            var value = await _daprClient.GetStateAsync<string>("statestore", key);
            return Ok(value);
        }
        [HttpGet("{key}/{value}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Post(string key,string value)
        {
            await _daprClient.SaveStateAsync("statestore", key, value);
            return Ok(value);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the component file (config.yaml) is not correct.

This is the format as mentioned in the [docs](https://docs.dapr.io/reference/components-reference/supported-state-stores/setup-inmemory/):

```yaml
apiVersion: dapr.io/v1alpha1
kind: Component
metadata:
  name: <NAME>
spec:
  type: state.in-memory
  version: v1
  metadata: []
```

You need to replace `<NAME>` with the name you give to this component. Let's say you'll use `inmemory-store`. You then need to refer to this component name in your C# code whenever you use the State Management API:

```cs
var value = await _daprClient.GetStateAsync<string>("inmemory-store", key);
return Ok(value);
```

If you need more help, have a look at the state management [quickstart](https://docs.dapr.io/getting-started/quickstarts/statemanagement-quickstart/). There's also a [Dapr Discord](https://discord.com/invite/ptHhX6jc34) you could join to ask more questions.